# c# Dijkstra adjacency list implementation

Tags: c#, algorithm, graph-algorithm, dijkstra

i have a problem in implementing Dijkstra's algorithm using adjacency list
i have tried it a lot but i don't know how to implement it

this is my graph class using adjacency list

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace testMapRouting
{
 #region Node Class
class Node
{
    public double speed { get; set; }
    public double time { get; set; }
    public double distance { get; set; }
    public double xCord;
    public double yCord;
    public int source { get; set; }
    public int destenation { get; set; }

    public Node() { }
    public Node(int Source)
    {
        this.source = Source;    
    }
    public Node(int Source,double _xOnMap,double _yOnMap)
    {
        this.xCord = _xOnMap;
        this.yCord = _yOnMap;
        this.source = Source;
        this.speed = 5.0;
    }
    public Node(int SOURCE, int DESTENATION, double SPEED, double DISTANCE)
    {
        this.source = SOURCE;
        this.destenation = DESTENATION;
        this.speed = SPEED;
        this.distance = DISTANCE;
        this.time = this.distance / this.speed;
    }

    #region overRide
    /// <summary>
    /// Overriding the Equal Methos"same as =="
    /// to Help me implement some functions
    /// </summary>

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var item = obj as Node;
        if (item == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return this.source.Equals(item.source);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.source.GetHashCode();
    }
    #endregion
}
#endregion
#region Graph Class
class Graph<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    #region Instance Variables
    ///<summary>
    ///Instance Variables
    /// </summary>
    ///
    private const long EMPTY_EDGE_VALUE = 0;
    protected virtual int _edgeCount { get; set; }
    public virtual Dictionary<Node, LinkedList<Node>> _adjacencyList { get; set; }
    #endregion
    #region Constructors
    ///<summary>
    ///Constructors
    /// </summary>
    /// 

    public Graph()
    {
        _edgeCount = 0;
        _adjacencyList = new Dictionary<Node, LinkedList<Node>>();
    }
    #endregion
    #region main Functions

    /// <summary>
    /// add new edge to Graph
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">source vertex</param>
    /// <param name="Destenation">Destenation vertex</param>
    /// <param name="speed"> Speed value</param>
    /// <param name="Distance"> Distance value</param>
    public void addEdge(Node source, Node Destenation, double speed, double Distance)
    {
        if (_adjacencyList.Count <= 0)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("addEdge: There are no Vertices in Graph.\n");
        }
        else
        {
            if (_adjacencyList.ContainsKey(source) && _adjacencyList.ContainsKey(Destenation))
            {
                var sourceEdge = new Node(source.source, Destenation.source, speed, Distance);
                var destenationEdge = new Node(Destenation.source, source.source, speed, Distance);

                    _adjacencyList[source].AddLast(sourceEdge);
                    _adjacencyList[Destenation].AddLast(destenationEdge);

                    ++_edgeCount;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new NullReferenceException("addEdge : Source or Destenation Vetrtex Don't Exist in Graph.\n");
            }
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// add a new vertex to graph
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    public void addVertex(Node value)
    {
        if (!_adjacencyList.ContainsKey(value))
        {
            LinkedList<Node> connections = new LinkedList<Node>();
            _adjacencyList.Add(value, connections);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("addVertex : This Vertex allready exists in Graph.\n");
        }

    }


    #endregion
    #region Utility Functions
    ///<summary>
    ///Utility Functions
    /// </summary>


    ///<summary>
    ///return edges count in the Graph
    /// </summary>
    public int edgeCount()
    {
        return _edgeCount;
    }

    ///<summary>
    ///return vertices count in the Graph
    /// </summary>
    public int verticesCount()
    {
        return _adjacencyList.Count;
    }

    //utility function to return the node with minimum
    //time edge
    // A utility function to print 
    // the constructed distance array 
   public void printSolution(double[] time, int n)
    {
        Console.Write("Vertex     Distance " +
                            "from Source\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            Console.Write(i + " \t\t " +
                        time[i] + "\n");
    }
```

The Problem is in this function i cant implement it right can you tell me what is the problem

```
   public void dijkstra(Graph<T> myGraph,Node start,Node end)
    {
        bool[] shortestPath = new bool[_adjacencyList.Count];          
        double[] time = new double[_adjacencyList.Count];
        SortedSet<int> queue = new SortedSet<int>(); //mafrod priority queue
        int[] Parent = new int[_adjacencyList.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < _adjacencyList.Count; i++)
        {
            time[i] = int.MaxValue;
            shortestPath[i] = false;
        }
        Parent[0] = -1;
        time[start.source] = 0;
        queue.Add(start.source);

        for(int v = 0; v < _adjacencyList.Count - 1; v++)
        {
            //int u = Minimum_NodeTime(time,shortestpath);
            int u = queue.Min();
            shortestPath[u] = true;
            Node tmp = new Node(u);
            foreach (var node in _adjacencyList[tmp])
            {
                if (!shortestPath[v] && time[u] + node.time < time[v])
                {
                    time[v] = time[u] + node.time;
                    Parent[v] = u;
                }
            }
        }

        printSolution(time, _adjacencyList.Count);

    }

    ///<summary>
    ///Returns a list of vertices
    /// </summary>
    public List<Node> Vertices()
    {
        List<Node> Vert = new List<Node>();
        foreach (var vertex in _adjacencyList)
        {
            Vert.Add(vertex.Key);
        }
        return Vert;

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Display Graph Content
    /// </summary>
    public void cout()
    {
        if (_adjacencyList.Count <= 0)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("cout: Graph is empty.\n");
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var vertex in _adjacencyList)
            {
                if (vertex.Value.Count <= 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Vertex :" + vertex.Key.source.ToString() + "  has Connections: ");

                    Console.WriteLine("cout: This vertex is disconnected.");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("##############################################");
                    Console.WriteLine("Vertex :" + vertex.Key.source.ToString() + "  has Connections: ");
                    foreach (var node in vertex.Value)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------");
                        Console.WriteLine("Source : " + node.source.ToString());
                        Console.WriteLine("Destenation : " + node.destenation.ToString());
                        Console.WriteLine("Speed : " + node.speed.ToString());
                        Console.WriteLine("Distance : " + node.distance.ToString());
                        Console.WriteLine("Time : " + node.time.ToString());
                        Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------");

                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("##############################################");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
#endregion
}
```

I looked at the Dijkstra's implementation Multiple times and i don't know what to do.

Comment: This isn't a service for debugging your buggy code. See https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for advice on how to learn to debug small programs like this. If you have a **specific** question, by all means ask that question, but "I wrote incorrect code and I don't know where the bug is" is not a question.

Comment: Some techniques that will help: (1) break up your program into many small methods, each of which does one thing well, and then individually test those methods. (2) follow the conventions and practices of C#; it will make your code easier to read, understand and debug. Your code is a mass of small formatting and naming errors, which makes me think that you are sloppy and do not pay attention to details, and of course code is buggy when you are sloppy and do not pay attention to details. Start paying attention to even the smallest details.

Comment: I do not like your dictionary : public virtual Dictionary<Node, LinkedList<Node>> _adjacencyList { get; set; }.  The key to a dictionary should be a single object like an unique ID.  I usually impliment Dijkstra's by having a class Nodes and a class Paths (has a source, destination, distance, speed).  The each class has a List<Path>

Comment: (3) write test cases, and use those test cases to find the simplest scenario where your program produces a wrong result.  For example, does it work if there is a graph with only one node?  Does it work if there is a graph with two nodes? There are only a few graphs with three nodes; try all of them. And so on.  When you find a case that fails, work out by hand what was supposed to happen, and then see why you did not do that.

Comment: (4) You've done a good job writing a class that represents graphs. Write classes that represent all the concepts in the algorithm, like paths.  And again, **write independent unit tests that verify that each class is correct**.

Comment: If you do all these things, then **the code that you write should look very much like the pseudocode for the algorithm**.  For an example of what I mean, take a look at my implementation of A-star, which is a more sophisticated version of your path finding algorithm.  The code reads *almost exactly* like the pseudocode, which makes me feel confident that the algorithm is correct. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/10/10/path-finding-using-a-in-c-3-0-part-four/